# Optional input in C

Tags: c, user-input, scanf, clock, getchar

I was trying to write a digital clock program where I faced that problem. I want to give user the choice to exit the program, but whatever input function I use(scanf, getchar etc) the program stops until I enter an input(either yes or no) as well as the clock stops. This is not intended, the clock should run as long as user wants to exit. 
Is there any way in C to make input optional to the user?

Comment: Some basic code from this program you wrote would be very helpful. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Not in the C standard. You need to use platform-specific APIs or third-party libraries.

Comment: Can you refer to any such API or library? I am using windows.

Answer (score 3):

No. Classic IO is synchronous, which means requesting a line will block your program (you won't be able to do anything--the scheduler will skip you) until the line is read.

Signals were designed for what you want. On Unix,
`Ctrl-\` (send the foreground process the quit signal) will make the program quit. 
`Ctrl-c` (send the foreground process the interrupt signal) will more often than not result in an exit as well.

Exiting is the default reaction to receiving most signals, but you can handle signals differently, and then they serve as a kind of asynchronous input.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you actually want to wait for user input and run the clock meanwhile. If you receive any such input you want to act on it else keep running the clock. What happens when you use scanf/get char is it keeps waiting till there is actually a keyboard input. (getchar is more reactive than scanf. getchar will return with every key hit. Scanf will wait till enter is pressed.) What you actually want is logic that "if there is any key hit". kbhit is the answer for you. Your program will look something like following:

```
#include <conio.h>
...
while(1) {
    if ( kbhit() ) {
        // Read the user input and act on it.
    } else {
        // Update the clock.
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Kbhit did the job but I can't compile the code in dev-c, it only works in turbo-c. Then what is the remedy?

Comment: You're right. kbhit has portability issues. You have it defined in library conio.h. You will have to implement an equivalent in Linux. A common use of kbhit function is to test when the user has pressed a key in an interactive console application.  It does not consume the character and does not block. POSIX (and therefore Linux) lacks a similar function. Although it does not directly support this functionality, the GNU Curses library can be used to implement _kbhit() on Linux. Study of curses.h and ncurses.h should help. I have shared a link in last comment with a dummy implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `kbhit` function from `<conio.h>`

```
#include <conio.h>

...

while( !kbhit() )
{
     /* update clock */
     ...

}
```

`kbhit()` returns non-zero value if there is a key in the keyboard buffer, and zero otherwise.

Comment: Kbhit did the job but I can't compile the code in dev-c, it only works in turbo-c. Then what is the remedy?

Comment: As some of the people mentioned it's not part of the C standard so not all dev environments have it. If you develop in Linux you may try using the kbhit() implementation from this [thread](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/63166-kbhit-linux.html) (check the second post)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, standard C (scanf(), getchar() etc.) uses line-buffered input. Whatever the user enters on the terminal does not actually get passed to the program until the user presses ENTER.

There are functions that *do* query key presses without buffering, but they are not part of the standard library. There is [`getch()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) on Unixes from `<curses.h>`, and [`_getch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) from Windows' `<conio.h>`, for example.

Or the user could simply use `<Ctrl>-c` to exit the program...

Answer (score 0):

It might be tricky, but
You could make an infinite loop while reading on the standard input, and when the user enters the exit command, you return 0 to end it ?

Comment: I am using windows, how can user enter command? At this moment I can only close the program by pressing close button at tge upper right hand corner of the Dos window but I want to close the program within the program.

Answer (score 0):

The program could

```
1) set the console to 'raw' mode
2) set a interrupt handler for the keyboard inputs
3) the interrupt handler sets a global flag
4) the main/clock update function, on each loop,
   looks at the global flag and if the global flag is set, exits
```

Comment: I can't get your point, can you please explain what do you mean by 'raw mode'?